# API for xlsx processing

Tags: java, python

Hello all is there any api for processing xlsx file with same format like cell color, cell formatting etc. i want to open xlsx file in append mode and want to encrypt data of cell without changing its formatting. API may be in python or java.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at either [OpenPyXL](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/) or [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: I have tried it but i did not get proper documentation or example. i implemented using openpyxl and Apche POI its working fine but not getting same formatting.

Comment: I implemented it using Jython and Apache POI. Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39898408/104345

Answer (score 1):

Use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)....

```
package com.bridgex.connect.foundation.ui.payment;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;



import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;


public class test1 {


public static void main( String [] args ) {

    String fileName="D:\\testPOI.xls";
    //Read an Excel File and Store in a Vector
    Vector dataHolder=readExcelFile(fileName);
    //Print the data read
    printCellDataToConsole(dataHolder);
}
public static Vector readExcelFile(String fileName)
{
    /** --Define a Vector
        --Holds Vectors Of Cells
     */
    Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();

    try{
    /** Creating Input Stream**/
    //InputStream myInput= ReadExcelFile.class.getResourceAsStream( fileName );
    FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);

    /** Create a POIFSFileSystem object**/
    POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

    /** Create a workbook using the File System**/
     HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

     /** Get the first sheet from workbook**/
    HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

    /** We now need something to iterate through the cells.**/
      Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();

      while(rowIter.hasNext()){
          HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
          Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
          Vector cellStoreVector=new Vector();
          while(cellIter.hasNext()){
              HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
              cellStoreVector.addElement(myCell);
          }
          cellVectorHolder.addElement(cellStoreVector);
      }
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }
    return cellVectorHolder;
}

private static void printCellDataToConsole(Vector dataHolder) {

    for (int i=0;i<dataHolder.size(); i++){
               Vector cellStoreVector=(Vector)dataHolder.elementAt(i);
        for (int j=0; j < cellStoreVector.size();j++){
            HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell)cellStoreVector.elementAt(j);
            String stringCellValue =  myCell.toString();
            System.out.print(stringCellValue+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

}
```